# 401 Unauthorized for System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials

Tags: c#, windows, ssas, mdx, olap

I'm developing a little thing called OLAP Action for SQL Server Analysis Services Multidimensional. It's a piece of C# code that does some things that are not possible from OLAP database. In this case, I'm querying OData Web client and returning some data from it. OLAP Action itself has some authentication settings like:
- User current users credentials
- Impersonate as Windows user(Username, password)

This OLAP action is located on a different server than the client which is executing it. Inside it, authentication to OData looks like this:

```
var wc = new WebClient();
wc.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                    wc.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
wc.Headers["Accept"] = "application/json;odata=nometadata";
```

The premise is that user connecting to OLAP database and executing this action has also access to OData, as his credentials are used in the authentication process, that's why setting for OLAP action is "Impersonate current user".
Problem is that when executing this action (by a simble CALL ASSP.QueryOData() MDX) error 401 - Unauthorized is returned. BUT if I change authentication option to Impersonate Windows user and put in the EXACT credentials of WIndows user that tried to execute the action before, it works.

I tried things like

```
wc.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;

ICredentials creds = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
                    NetworkCredential crenet = creds.GetCredential(uri, "Basic");
                    wc.Credentials = crenet;

NetworkCredential netCred = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials.GetCredential(uri, "NTLM");
                    wc.Credentials = netCred;
```

But neither of them works. I'm running out of ideas and basically was hoping for a clue what might be wrong. This setup works in test environment, so I'm guessing there's something wrong with settings of server/client.

Comment: can you show us more code of how you are getting the credentials please

Comment: There's not much more logic than what I posted. After passing Credentials to WebClient I read the response:
System.IO.Stream response = wc.OpenRead(conn);
                        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response);
                        jsonbefore = reader.ReadToEnd();
                        response.Flush();

Comment: so what are the acutal credentials being passed when it does work vs what does work ?

Comment: How does the authentication with the OData server happen? Kerberos? NTLM? Basic? Digest? I think if not Kerberos, you might be out of luck, and Kerberos needs some very specific configuration settings to work.